# Regex for URL routing - match alphanumeric and dashes except words in this list

Tags: regex, codeigniter, url-routing, regex-negation

I'm using CodeIgniter to write an app where a user will be allowed to register an account and is assigned a URL (URL slug)  of their choosing (ex. domain.com/user-name). CodeIgniter has a URL routing feature that allows the utilization of regular expressions ([link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)).

User's are only allowed to register URL's that contain alphanumeric characters, dashes (-), and under scores (_). This is the regex I'm using to verify the validity of the URL slug: `^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,254}$`

I am using the url routing feature to route a few url's to features on my site (ex. `/home -> /pages/index`, `/activity -> /user/activity`) so those particular URL's obviously cannot be registered by a user.

I'm largely inexperienced with regular expressions but have attempted to write an expression that would match any URL slugs with alphanumerics/dash/underscore except if they are any of the following:

1. default_controller
2. 404_override
3. home
4. activity

Here is the code I'm using to try to match the words with that specific criteria:

```
$route['(?!default_controller|404_override|home|activity)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,254}'] = 'view/slug/$1';
```

but it isn't routing properly.  Can someone help? (side question: is it necessary to have `^` or `$` in the regex when trying to match with URL's?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Alright, let's pick this apart.

**Ignore CodeIgniter's reserved routes.**

The `default_controller` and `404_override` portions of your route are unnecessary. Routes are compared to the requested URI to see if there's a match. It is highly unlikely that those two items will ever be in your URI, since they are special reserved routes for CodeIgniter. So let's forget about them.

```
$route['(?!home|activity)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,254}'] = 'view/slug/$1';
```

**Capture everything!**

With regular expressions, a group is created using parentheses `()`. This group can then be retrieved with a back reference - in our case, the `$1, $2, etc.` located in the second part of the route. You only had a group around the first set of items you were trying to exclude, so it would not properly capture the entire wild card. You found this out yourself already, and added a group around the entire item (good!).

```
$route['((?!home|activity)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,254})'] = 'view/slug/$1';
```

**Look-ahead?!**

On that subject, the first group around `home|activity` is not actually a traditional group, due to the use of `?!` at the beginning. This is called a [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and it's a complicated regular expression feature. And it's being used incorrectly:

> *Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else.*

There's a LOT more I could go into with this, but basically we don't really want or need it in the first place, so I'll let you explore if you'd like.

In order to make your life easier, I'd suggest separating the home, activity, and other existing controllers in the routes. CodeIgniter will look through the list of routes from top to bottom, and once something matches, it stops checking. So if you specify your existing controllers *before* the wild card, they will match, and your wild card regular expression can be greatly simplified.

```
$route['home'] = 'pages';
$route['activity'] = 'user/activity';
$route['([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,254})'] = 'view/slug/$1';
```

Remember to list your routes in order from most specific to least. Wild card matches are less specific than exact matches (like home and activity), so they should come after (below).

#### Now, that's all the complicated stuff. A little more FYI.

Remember that dashes `-` have a special meaning when in between `[]` brackets. You should escape them if you want to match a literal dash.

```
$route['([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_\-]{2,254})'] = 'view/slug/$1';
```

Note that your character repetition min/max `{2,254}` only applies to the second set of characters, so your user names must be 3 characters at minimum, and 255 at maximum. Just an FYI if you didn't realize that already.

I saw your own answer to this problem, and it's just ugly. Sorry. The `^` and `$` symbols are used improperly throughout the lookahead (which still shouldn't be there in the first place). It may "work" for a few use cases that you're testing it with, but it will just give you problems and headaches in the future.

Hopefully now you know more about regular expressions and how they're matched in the routing process.

And to answer your question, no, you should not use `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of your regex -- CodeIgniter will add that for you.

---

#### Use the 404, Luke...

At this point your routes are improved and should be functional. I will throw it out there, though, that you might want to consider using the controller/method defined as the `404_override` to handle your wild cards. The main benefit of this is that you don't need ANY routes to direct a wild card, or to prevent your wild card from goofing up existing controllers. You only need:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'view/slug';
```

Then, your View::slug() method would check the URI, and see if it's a valid pattern, then check if it exists as a user (same as your slug method does now, no doubt). If it does, then you're good to go. If it doesn't, then you throw a 404 error.

It may not seem that graceful, but it works great. Give it a shot if it sounds better for you.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. Not only did you help me answer my questions, you also helped me learn a few new things that made me look at things a little differently. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with codeIgniter specifically, but most frameworks routing operate based on precedence.  In other words, the default controller, 404, etc routes should be defined first.  Then you can simplify your regex to only match the slugs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok answering my own question

I've seem to come up with a different expression that works:

```
$route['(^(?!default_controller$|404_override$|home$|activity$)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]{2,254}$)'] = 'view/slug/$1';
```

I added parenthesis around the whole expression (I think that's what CodeIgniter matches with `$1` on the right) and added a start of line identifier: `^` and a bunch of end of line identifiers: `$`

Hope this helps someone who may run into this problem later.